# Assigning sessions with SQL for user app activity data over a window

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, window-functions, analysis

I am trying to understand a piece of this code from Mode's case study, where the goal is to assign individual "sessions" to user activity (this code) and then segment it by activity type (not included here). A session is defined as 10 minutes of activity.

The goal of the overall analysis is to segment the original data into number of sessions with "search autocomplete" vs number of sessions with "complete search runs" and analyze them as a timeseries over ten weeks to see which feature is used the most. This piece of code is to only tackle the "sessions" piece first.

The code:

```
SELECT bounds.*,
                CASE WHEN last_event >= INTERVAL '10 MINUTE' THEN id
                WHEN last_event IS NULL THEN id
                ELSE LAG(id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY occurred_at) END AS session
FROM (
      SELECT user_id,
        event_type,
        event_name,
        occurred_at,
        occurred_at - LAG(occurred_at,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY occurred_at) AS last_event,
        LEAD(occurred_at,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY occurred_at) - occurred_at AS next_event,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id
      FROM tutorial.yammer_events e
      WHERE e.event_type = 'engagement'
      ORDER BY user_id,occurred_at
      ) as bounds
```

The output is as follows:

```
user_id |event_type |event_name |occurred_at    |   last_event | next_event | id | session
4        engagement login        5/13/2014 9:31                    0:00:23     1    1
4        engagement home_page    5/13/2014 9:32     0:00:23        0:00:16     2    1 <---
4        engagement search_auto  5/13/2014 9:32     0:00:16        0:00:32     3    2 <---
4        engagement search_auto  5/13/2014 9:32     0:00:32      6 days :32    4    3
4        engagement login        5/20/2014 9:31    6 days :32      0:00:25     5    5
4        engagement search_auto  5/20/2014 9:31     0:00:25        0:00:01     6    5
4        engagement home_page    5/20/2014 9:31      0:00:01       0:00:03     7    6
```

My problem is with the highlighted output (just one example of many). Due to the "LAG" in code, what should be session 1 is being labeled as session 2.

My two questions are:

1. Is this the right approach and code of labeling sessions (I am new to such analysis)? If yes, why so?
2. If not, what would be the fix to label the sessions accurately?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question needs to describe the logic for assigning sessions.  Otherwise, it is rather hard to judge whether code is doing the right thing or not.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit and add the full scope of analysis.

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay, edited. Hopefully this is descriptive.